# Removing rows with 'junk data'

Tags: r

Is there a way to **remove** the rows containing 'junk' data? In this case, junk data would be defined as having punctuation, symbols or letters. So once the junk data has been removed, the only data left should be those that are numeric.

```
test<-c(12,123,2435,1231,121,'a!12','12fb','gr32#')
x<-data.frame(test)
```

Comment: in this case you can use as.numeric() on test and then filter out NAs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use regex to select only digits (`[0-9]+`) from start (`^`) to end (`$`) in `filter` and then convert to `numeric` (if needed).

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
x %>% 
   filter(str_detect(test, "^[0-9]+$"))
# test
#1   12
#2  123
#3 2435
#4 1231
#5  121
```

---

Or with `subset` and `grepl` from `base R`

```
subset(x, grepl("^[0-9]+$", test))
```

Comment: What if there are multiple columns in the data frame with some rows containing junk data? So, if the first column of a row is 'clean' and the next column of the same row has 'junk' data, then that entire row will be removed because of the 2nd column

Comment: @ElliotTan. In that case, you can do `x %>% filter_at(vars(colNms), all_vars(str_detect(., "^[0-9]+$")))`. Or using `base R`, i1 <- Reduce("&", lapply(x[colNms], grepl, pattern = "^[0-9]+$"))` and then use it to subset `x[i1, , drop = FALSE]`

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the data to numeric and then remove `NA` values

```
x <- data.frame(test, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
x[!is.na(as.numeric(x$test)), , drop =  FALSE]

#  test
#1   12
#2  123
#3 2435
#4 1231
#5  121
```

Or using regular expressions, we can drop rows which contain anything other than numbers.

```
x[!grepl("[^0-9]", x$test), , drop = FALSE]
#OR
#x[grep("[^0-9]", x$test, invert = TRUE), , drop = FALSE]
```

**data**

```
x <- data.frame(test, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```